# How to create Dataflow using Bean that processes three rest calls concurrently

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have three endpoints which I need to query concurrently using Apache Beam in Java.

The endpoints are stored in a Set.

I would like to create three concurrent Dataflow tasks that query these endpoints.

I have no idea how to do it. Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Control parallelism in Apache Beam Dataflow pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608212/control-parallelism-in-apache-beam-dataflow-pipeline)